# node names and nested loops in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to draw a (part of a) lattice. To achieve that I use two nested foreach loops, like this:

```
\foreach \x in {-1, 0, 1} {
    \foreach \y in {0, 1, 2} {
        \path node (\x.\y) at (\x+\y-1, \y-\x) {};
    }
}
```

Anyway I'm not able to refer to the nodes I create in the code above. Specifically, if I try something like this:

```
\path[->] (0.0) edge [bend right = 30] (0.1);
```

I get an error:

```
ERROR: Package pgf Error: No shape named 0 is known.
```

So the question is: which name will TikZ accept? The names should correspond to the lattice points. So, in some way, they should contain \x and \y.

Trying to variate on the nodes name doesn't help either. For example, if I try this

```
\path node (X\x Y\y) at (\x+\y-1, \y-\x) {};
```

I still get the same error:

```
ERROR: Package pgf Error: No shape named X0 Y0 is known.
```

Comment: Ok, I used (N\x_\y) and it works. Still the question remains, what is the required format for node names?

Comment: Basically, you can use anything you want, with some exceptions (see my answer), that won't "confuse" `pgf`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz} 

\begin{document} 

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex,scale=2]
\foreach \x in {-1, 0, 1} {
    \foreach \y in {0, 1, 2} {
        \path node (\x-\y) at (\x+\y-1, \y-\x) {};
    }
}
\path[->] (0-0) edge [bend right = 30] (0-1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

From the `pgf` documentation (Section **3.7 Naming Nodes** ):

> Names for nodes can be pretty arbitrary, but they should not contain
>   commas, periods, parentheses, colons, and some other special
>   characters. However, they can contain underscores and hyphens.

Answer (score 12):

To add to Gonzalo's answer, the reason why periods specifically shouldn't be used in node names is because they already have a special meaning when dealing with nodes.  When you name a node, as in `\node (mynode) at (0,0) {hello};` then TikZ sets a set of "anchors" around the node.  The format for referencing these anchors is `nodename.anchor`.  So we have `mynode.north` and `mynode.north east`, and also angular anchors such as `mynode.90` and `mynode.-10`.  The parser looks for the `.` in the reference and when it sees `something.something else` then it interprets that as `nodename = something` and `anchor = something else`.  This happens *before* it looks to see if `nodename` actually exists.  Then it tests for existence, and if it doesn't find it then it bails out.

Commas are also pretty easy to explain as `(x,y)` is the usual syntax for coordinates, and `x` and `y` don't need to initially be just numbers.

Parentheses would probably also confuse the parser as they are often used for special syntaxes (especially with the `calc` library).

Colons are used in the polar coordinate syntax, so that explains why you should avoid them.

The reason that:

```
\path node (X\x Y\y) at (\x+\y-1, \y-\x) {};
```

doesn't work is something else.  This is because TeX swallows spaces after a command.  So the node name gets set to the expansion of `X\x Y\y` which is, for example, `X-1Y0` as the space after `\x` is eaten up.  To get an actual space, you should use the `\space` macro or put an "empty" token after the `\x`.  Thus either `X\x\space Y\y` or `X\x{} Y\y` will do.

Here's a bit of code that might be useful for you.

```
\makeatletter
\tikzset{%
  show node name/.code={%
    \expandafter\def\expandafter\tikz@mode\expandafter{\tikz@mode\show\tikz@fig@name}%
    }
}
\makeatother
```

If you put that in your preamble, it puts in a little bit of code that displays the node name in the log.  Use it as `\node[show node name] ...`.

Comment: Thanks, that was very helpful! I suppose though, I have to accept the other answer. Since it answers the actual question, whereas this is an extension. Anyway, I really appreciate your answer.

Comment: `the_code >> tex-snippets.tex`: Thanks Andrew for this useful bit of background information. The `show node name` style is just neat!