# Arrows coordinates in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to write a macro that uses TikZ to create a photo like this:

[image: example]
<sub>(source: [msdn.com](http://blogs.msdn.com/cfs-filesystemfile.ashx/__key/communityserver-components-postattachments/00-07-14-56-31/Slide1.jpg))</sub>  .

But, finally I came up with something like this:

[image: TikZ Picture]

As you see, the problem is that the arrows go to the wrong side of the end circle (they always go to the right side). Here is the source code of my example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc} 
\makeatletter 
\@namedef{color@1}{red!40}
\@namedef{color@2}{green!40}   
\@namedef{color@3}{blue!40} 
\@namedef{color@4}{cyan!40}  
\@namedef{color@5}{magenta!40} 
\@namedef{color@6}{yellow!40}    

\newcommand{\graphitemize}[1]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={align=center}]  

\foreach \gritem [count=\xi] in {#1}  {\global\let\maxgritem\xi}  

\foreach \gritem [count=\xi] in {#1}
{% 
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\angle}{360/\maxgritem*\xi}
\edef\col{\@nameuse{color@\xi}}
\node[circle,
     ultra thick,
     draw=white,
     fill opacity=.5,
     fill=\col,
     minimum size=3cm] (satellite\xi) at (\angle:4cm) {\gritem };
}%

\foreach \gritem [count=\xi] in {#1}
{% 
\pgfmathsetmacro{\xj}{mod(\xi, \maxgritem) + 1}
\edef\col{\@nameuse{color@\xi}}
\draw[<-,line width=.5cm,opacity=.5,\col] (satellite\xj) to[bend left] (satellite\xi);
}%
\end{tikzpicture}  
}%

\begin{document}

\graphitemize{Phase 1,Phase 2, Phase 3, Phase 4}

\end{document}
```

Note that I adapted the code from Altermundus answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52394/high-level-macros-and-environments-based-on-tikz). How can I fix the end position of the arrows?

Comment: You should wrap your `\draw` command for the arrows in `\begin{scope}[opacity=.5,transparency group] ... \end{scope}` to make sure that the arrow lines and arrow tips have the same colour. Also, note that `fill opacity=0.5` also makes the text semitransparent in your nodes, so you should set `text opacity=1` after `fill opacity`. Lastly, if there are no objects behind the graph, you might as well just choose lighter colours, instead of using transparency.

Comment: Indeed, instead of `opacity=.5,\col`  you can use `\col\relax!0.5`.

Comment: I don't know if we have a canonical "What are legal TikZ node names" or not, but maybe we should!  In the meantime, here's a similar situation: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/28242/86

Comment: @AndrewStacey I read percusse's answer after your comment :(

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pointing to a node with calculated name, why do I get to the east, not to the center?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161532/pointing-to-a-node-with-calculated-name-why-do-i-get-to-the-east-not-to-the-ce) {p/s while this question is older, I think the other question has a more descriptive title, thus I vote to close in that direction)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem comes from the math operation `mod(\xi, \maxgritem) + 1`. TikZ is giving the result with a number with decimal point such as `1.0, 2.0` etc. and later since you use it in the node naming it becomes `satellite1.0,satellite2.0`. Coincidentally, this means that the arrow shoud go to the node border at zero angle, hence the weird right side tracking.

You can fix it easily by replacing the operation line with

```
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\xj}{mod(\xi, \maxgritem) + 1)}
```