# Hobby path realization in convex hull approach

Tags: tikz-pgf, highlighting, hobby, curve-fitting

#### Motivation

In the answer
[Highlight a group of nodes in a tikz tree](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70999/highlight-a-group-of-nodes-in-a-tikz-tree#71064), Jake suggested combining the convex hull approach from [padded boundary of convex hull](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27171/padded-boundary-of-convex-hull#27185) with the *hobby path* and I was really intrigued by the possibility.

#### Preliminary work

At first I tried to modify at least as possible the `\convexpath`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{hobby,backgrounds,calc,trees}

\newcommand{\myconvexpath}[2]{
[   
    create hobbyhullnodes/.code={
        \global\edef\namelist{#1}
        \foreach [count=\counter] \nodename in \namelist {
            \global\edef\numberofnodes{\counter}
            \node at (\nodename) [draw=none,name=hobbyhullnode\counter] {};
        }
        \node at (hobbyhullnode\numberofnodes) [name=hobbyhullnode0,draw=none] {};
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro\lastnumber{\numberofnodes+1}
        \node at (hobbyhullnode1) [name=hobbyhullnode\lastnumber,draw=none] {};
    },
    create hobbyhullnodes
]
($(hobbyhullnode1)!#2!-90:(hobbyhullnode0)$)
\foreach [
    evaluate=\currentnode as \previousnode using \currentnode-1,
    evaluate=\currentnode as \nextnode using \currentnode+1
    ] \currentnode in {1,...,\numberofnodes} {
   let \p1 = ($(hobbyhullnode\currentnode)!#2!-90:(hobbyhullnode\previousnode) - (hobbyhullnode\currentnode)$),
    \n1 = {atan2(\x1,\y1)},
    \p2 = ($(hobbyhullnode\currentnode)!#2!90:(hobbyhullnode\nextnode) - (hobbyhullnode\currentnode)$),
    \n2 = {atan2(\x2,\y2)},
    \n{delta} = {-Mod(\n1-\n2,360)}
  in 
    {arc [start angle=\n1, delta angle=\n{delta}, radius=#2]}
     ..($(hobbyhullnode\nextnode)!0.5!(hobbyhullnode\currentnode)$)
     ..($(hobbyhullnode\nextnode)!#2!-90:(hobbyhullnode\currentnode)$)
}
--cycle
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[use Hobby shortcut]
\node (f) {f}
    child { node (g) {g}
      child { node (a) {a}
    }
      child { node (b) {b}
    }
  }
    child { node (h) {h}
      child { node (c) {c}
    }
  };
  \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
  \fill[draw,blue, opacity=0.3] \myconvexpath{f,h,c,g}{12pt};
  \fill[draw,red, opacity=0.3] \myconvexpath{g,b,a}{12pt};
  \end{pgfonlayer}
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

which leads to:

[image]

I suspected the combination of `arcs` with the *hobby* path was the cause of cusps, so in another example I tried with:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{hobby,backgrounds,calc,trees}

\newcommand{\myconvexpath}[2]{
[   
    create hobbyhullnodes/.code={
        \global\edef\namelist{#1}
        \foreach [count=\counter] \nodename in \namelist {
            \global\edef\numberofnodes{\counter}
            \node at (\nodename) [draw=none,name=hobbyhullnode\counter] {};
        }
        \node at (hobbyhullnode\numberofnodes) [name=hobbyhullnode0,draw=none] {};
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro\lastnumber{\numberofnodes+1}
        \node at (hobbyhullnode1) [name=hobbyhullnode\lastnumber,draw=none] {};
    },
    create hobbyhullnodes
]
($(hobbyhullnode1)!#2!-90:(hobbyhullnode0)$)
\foreach [
    evaluate=\currentnode as \previousnode using \currentnode-1,
    evaluate=\currentnode as \nextnode using \currentnode+1
    ] \currentnode in {1,...,\numberofnodes} {
   let \p1 = ($(hobbyhullnode\currentnode)!#2!-90:(hobbyhullnode\previousnode)$),
    \n1 = {atan2(\x1,\y1)},
    \p2 = ($(hobbyhullnode\currentnode)!#2!90:(hobbyhullnode\nextnode)$),
    \n2 = {atan2(\x2,\y2)},
    \n{delta} = {-Mod(\n1-\n2,360)},
    \n{end}={add(\n1,\n{delta})}
  in 
    {..([in angle=\n1]$(hobbyhullnode\currentnode)!#2!-90:(hobbyhullnode\previousnode)$)..([out angle=\n{end}]$(hobbyhullnode\currentnode)!#2!90:(hobbyhullnode\nextnode)$)}
     ..($(hobbyhullnode\nextnode)!0.5!(hobbyhullnode\currentnode)$)
     ..($(hobbyhullnode\nextnode)!#2!-90:(hobbyhullnode\currentnode)$)
}
--cycle
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[use Hobby shortcut]
\node (f) {f}
    child { node (g) {g}
      child { node (a) {a}
    }
      child { node (b) {b}
    }
  }
    child { node (h) {h}
      child { node (c) {c}
    }
  };
  \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
  \fill[draw,blue, opacity=0.3] \myconvexpath{f,h,c,g}{12pt};
  \fill[draw,red, opacity=0.3] \myconvexpath{g,b,a}{12pt};
  \end{pgfonlayer}
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

that gives a not promising result:

[image]

#### Question

Is there a way to automatically recognize the node angle a path will fall when arrives near it? Doing things by hand, one can force a path to follow the desired direction, for example, `h.north -> h.east -> h.south`, but how is it possible to do it automatically without the `arc` syntax?

Notice that, for some shapes, one could proceed as follows:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{hobby,backgrounds,calc,trees}

\newcommand{\hobbyconvexpath}[2]{
[   
    create hobbyhullnodes/.code={
        \global\edef\namelist{#1}
        \foreach [count=\counter] \nodename in \namelist {
            \global\edef\numberofnodes{\counter}
            \node at (\nodename) [draw=none,name=hobbyhullnode\counter] {};
        }
        \node at (hobbyhullnode\numberofnodes) [name=hobbyhullnode0,draw=none] {};
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro\lastnumber{\numberofnodes+1}
        \node at (hobbyhullnode1) [name=hobbyhullnode\lastnumber,draw=none] {};
    },
    create hobbyhullnodes
]
($(hobbyhullnode1)!#2!-40:(hobbyhullnode0)$)
\foreach [
    evaluate=\currentnode as \previousnode using \currentnode-1,
    evaluate=\currentnode as \nextnode using \currentnode+1
    ] \currentnode in {1,...,\numberofnodes} {
  let \p1 = ($(hobbyhullnode\currentnode)!#2!-90:(hobbyhullnode\previousnode) $),
    \n1 = {atan2(\x1,\y1)},
    \p2 = ($(hobbyhullnode\currentnode)!#2!-90:(hobbyhullnode\nextnode)$),
    \n2 = {atan2(\x2,\y2)},
    \n{delta} = {-Mod(\n1-\n2,360)},
    \n{fin}={add(\n1,\n{delta})}
  in 
      {..($(hobbyhullnode\currentnode)!#2!-220:(hobbyhullnode\previousnode)$)..($(hobbyhullnode\currentnode)!#2!40:(hobbyhullnode\nextnode)$)}
   %{arc [start angle=\n1, end angle=\n{fin}, radius=#2]}
     ..($(hobbyhullnode\nextnode)!0.5!(hobbyhullnode\currentnode)$)
     ..($(hobbyhullnode\nextnode)!#2!-40:(hobbyhullnode\currentnode)$)
}
--cycle
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[use Hobby shortcut]
  \foreach \place/\text in {{(1,0)/a},{(0,-1)/b},{(-1,0)/c},{(0,1)/d}}
  \node[name=\text] at \place {\text};
  \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
  \fill[draw,green, opacity=0.3] \hobbyconvexpath{a,b,c,d}{10pt};
  \end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

but in general is not a valid approach and it is still to improve, to get at least the same result of [Highlight a group of nodes in a tikz tree](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70999/highlight-a-group-of-nodes-in-a-tikz-tree#71064).

Comment: I'm not clear as to the *role* of Hobby's algorithm here.  That produces a passably smooth curve through a given set of points.  It is designed for when you don't know much about the curve other than those points.  Here, it would seem that you know too much about the curve for Hobby's algorithm to be of particular use.

Comment: @AndrewStacey: in your opinion a classical curve path construction `(pos)..controls (controll point)and(controll point)..` would give similar results? Actually, when I answered in [Highlight a group of nodes in a tikz tree](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70999/highlight-a-group-of-nodes-in-a-tikz-tree) I didn't considered the possibility...

Comment: What I suspect is that you'll want to put various constraints on the path and those will mean that the full power of Hobby's algorithm isn't used (there might be some use for computing the control points given the angles).  So I'd want to start by knowing what makes a "good" diagram and what characteristics it has.  If you'd like to discuss it, perhaps the "From Answers to Packages" chat room would be a good place.

Comment: Found some part of the solution here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121286/error-with-hobbyconvexpath

Answer (score 45, accepted):

*I'm answering because I think there's a quite good solution on the problem. First of all I'd like to thank [Andrew Stacey](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/86/andrew-stacey) because without the discussion in chat I wouldn't be able to solve this and, more important, he founds the major issue in the code.*

---

#### What I learnt

The answer to the question:

> Is there a way to automatically recognize the node angle a path will fall when arrives near it?

is actually: *TikZ already does it automatically.* Notice indeed that:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[circle,fill=red] (a) at (1,1) {}; 
\node[circle,fill=blue] (b) at  (3,2) {};
\draw[color=black] (a) -- (b);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

correctly leads to:

[image]

and the user should not have to care about the angle the line arrives near the blue node.

#### The major issue

Building on that, however, was not sufficient. Andrew recognized that the paths drawn were not correctly realized due to the fact that the hobby path shortcut construct separately each piece; this was the cause of the bizarre behaviour as per the second figure displayed in the question.

#### The intermediate result

With his help it was possible to get 
[(code here)](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6354943#6354943):

[image]

and notice how this solved the problems mentioned before.

#### A final result

Starting from the intermediate result I noticed that actually the non-perfect fit around some nodes was basically due to the `out angle`, that is the the path from hypothetically `($(hobbyhullnode1)!10pt!-90:(hobbyhullnode0)$)..($(hobbyhullnode1)!10pt!90:(hobbyhullnode0)$)`. With a bit of care, the right angle should have been set to `180` rather than `90`.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2bp]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,calc,trees,hobby}

\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main}

\newcommand{\hobbyconvexpath}[2]{
[   
    create hobbyhullnodes/.code={
        \global\edef\namelist{#1}
        \foreach [count=\counter] \nodename in \namelist {
            \global\edef\numberofnodes{\counter}
            \node at (\nodename)
[draw=none,name=hobbyhullnode\counter] {};
        }
        \node at (hobbyhullnode\numberofnodes)
[name=hobbyhullnode0,draw=none] {};
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro\lastnumber{\numberofnodes+1}
        \node at (hobbyhullnode1)
[name=hobbyhullnode\lastnumber,draw=none] {};
    },
    create hobbyhullnodes
]
($(hobbyhullnode1)!#2!-90:(hobbyhullnode0)$)
\pgfextra{
  \gdef\hullpath{}
\foreach [
    evaluate=\currentnode as \previousnode using \currentnode-1,
    evaluate=\currentnode as \nextnode using \currentnode+1
    ] \currentnode in {1,...,\numberofnodes} {
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\thecurrentnode\currentnode
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\thepreviousnode\previousnode
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\thenextnode\nextnode
    \xdef\hullpath{\hullpath    
  ..($(hobbyhullnode\thecurrentnode)!#2!180:(hobbyhullnode\thepreviousnode)$)
  ..($(hobbyhullnode\thenextnode)!0.5!(hobbyhullnode\thecurrentnode)$)}
    \ifx\currentnode\numberofnodes
    \xdef\hullpath{\hullpath .. cycle}
    \else
    \xdef\hullpath{\hullpath
  ..($(hobbyhullnode\thenextnode)!#2!-90:(hobbyhullnode\thecurrentnode)$)}
    \fi
}
}
\hullpath
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[use Hobby shortcut,scale=3,transform shape]
\node (f) {f}
    child { node (g) {g} 
      child { node (a) {a}
    }
      child { node (b) {b}
    }
  }
    child { node (h) {h}
      child { node (c) {c}
      }
  };

\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
\fill[red,opacity=0.3] \hobbyconvexpath{a,g,b}{10pt};
\end{pgfonlayer}

\draw[blue,dashed]($(hobbyhullnode1)!10pt!-90:(hobbyhullnode0)$)--
($(hobbyhullnode1)!10pt!-90:(hobbyhullnode0)$)..($(hobbyhullnode1)!10pt!180:(hobbyhullnode0)$)..
($(hobbyhullnode2)!0.5!(hobbyhullnode1)$) ..
($(hobbyhullnode2)!10pt!-90:(hobbyhullnode1)$)..($(hobbyhullnode2)!10pt!180:(hobbyhullnode1)$)..($(hobbyhullnode3)!0.5!(hobbyhullnode2)$)..
($(hobbyhullnode3)!10pt!-90:(hobbyhullnode2)$)..($(hobbyhullnode3)!10pt!180:(hobbyhullnode2)$)
..($(hobbyhullnode4)!0.5!(hobbyhullnode3)$) .. cycle;

\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
\fill[green!50!lime,opacity=0.4] \hobbyconvexpath{g,f,h,c}{10pt};
\end{pgfonlayer}

\draw[blue,dashed]($(hobbyhullnode1)!10pt!-90:(hobbyhullnode0)$)--
($(hobbyhullnode1)!10pt!-90:(hobbyhullnode0)$)..($(hobbyhullnode1)!10pt!180:(hobbyhullnode0)$)..
($(hobbyhullnode2)!0.5!(hobbyhullnode1)$) ..
($(hobbyhullnode2)!10pt!-90:(hobbyhullnode1)$)..($(hobbyhullnode2)!10pt!180:(hobbyhullnode1)$)..($(hobbyhullnode3)!0.5!(hobbyhullnode2)$)..
($(hobbyhullnode3)!10pt!-90:(hobbyhullnode2)$)..($(hobbyhullnode3)!10pt!180:(hobbyhullnode2)$)
..($(hobbyhullnode4)!0.5!(hobbyhullnode3)$) ..
($(hobbyhullnode4)!10pt!-90:(hobbyhullnode3)$)..($(hobbyhullnode4)!10pt!180:(hobbyhullnode3)$)
..($(hobbyhullnode5)!0.5!(hobbyhullnode4)$) .. cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[use Hobby shortcut,scale=3,transform shape]
\node (f) {f}
    child { node (g) {g} 
      child { node (a) {a}
    }
      child { node (b) {b}
    }
  }
    child { node (h) {h}
      child { node (c) {c}
      }
  };

\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
\fill[orange,opacity=0.4] \hobbyconvexpath{a,g,h,b}{13pt};
\end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[use Hobby shortcut,scale=3,transform shape]
\node (f) {f}
    child { node (g) {g} 
      child { node (a) {a}
    }
      child { node (b) {b}
    }
  }
    child { node (h) {h}
      child { node (c) {c}
      }
  };

\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
\fill[cyan,opacity=0.4] \hobbyconvexpath{b,g,f,h}{10pt};
\end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

with the following result:

[image]

Another example (since I noticed that the shape highlighted is actually the same in all the three previous figures):

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[use Hobby shortcut,scale=3,transform shape]
\node (f) {f}
    child { node (g) {g} 
      child { node (a) {a}
        child { node (i) {i}}
    }
      child { node (b) {b}
            child { node (d) {d}}
            child { node (e) {e}}
    }
  }
    child { node (h) {h}
      child { node (c) {c}
      }
  };

\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
\fill[cyan,opacity=0.4] \hobbyconvexpath{a,g,f,b,e,d}{10pt};
\end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: Really nice!...

Comment: What a nice surprise!

Comment: The issue that lead to a non perfect alignment has been solved: I leave to the curious to check the code to understand _what was the problem_. `:)`

Comment: If the edit was the culprit you can instead use `evaluate=\currentnode as \previousnode using int(\currentnode-1)` so that the result is truncated. I think that might be the same issue that was in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52961/arrows-coordinates-in-tikz

Comment: @percusse: oh.. this can avoid some more definitions inside the foreach! Didn't came in my mind. Anyway, yes, the problem was exactly the same of that question.

Comment: I am running this through xelatex from mactex 2012 and I am getting the error: \fp_gset:Nn \g_hobby_paramc_fp {(3-5^.5)/2}

Comment: @macmadness86: try to update the distribution; I guess this should fix the problem.

Comment: *Note*: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/121286/86 if using the latest version of the `hobby` package as the `cycle` path specification is (at time of writing) no longer valid.

Comment: Is it possible to make it work also on TexLive 2013? I've noticed the problem issued by `closed=true`but I'm not able to fix it.