# compile error as xparse fails because it requires expl3 after 2013 update of texlive

Tags: xparse, hobby

I updated texlive to 2012 release. However, when I try to compile example code, which I obtained from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71638/hobby-path-realization-in-convex-hull-approach), my attempt fails.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2bp]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,calc,trees,hobby}

\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main}

\newcommand{\hobbyconvexpath}[2]{
[   
    create hobbyhullnodes/.code={
        \global\edef\namelist{#1}
        \foreach [count=\counter] \nodename in \namelist {
            \global\edef\numberofnodes{\counter}
            \node at (\nodename)
[draw=none,name=hobbyhullnode\counter] {};
        }
        \node at (hobbyhullnode\numberofnodes)
[name=hobbyhullnode0,draw=none] {};
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro\lastnumber{\numberofnodes+1}
        \node at (hobbyhullnode1)
[name=hobbyhullnode\lastnumber,draw=none] {};
    },
    create hobbyhullnodes
]
($(hobbyhullnode1)!#2!-90:(hobbyhullnode0)$)
\pgfextra{
  \gdef\hullpath{}
\foreach [
    evaluate=\currentnode as \previousnode using \currentnode-1,
    evaluate=\currentnode as \nextnode using \currentnode+1
    ] \currentnode in {1,...,\numberofnodes} {
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\thecurrentnode\currentnode
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\thepreviousnode\previousnode
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\thenextnode\nextnode
    \xdef\hullpath{\hullpath    
  ..($(hobbyhullnode\thecurrentnode)!#2!180:(hobbyhullnode\thepreviousnode)$)
  ..($(hobbyhullnode\thenextnode)!0.5!(hobbyhullnode\thecurrentnode)$)}
    \ifx\currentnode\numberofnodes
    \xdef\hullpath{\hullpath .. cycle}
    \else
    \xdef\hullpath{\hullpath
  ..($(hobbyhullnode\thenextnode)!#2!-90:(hobbyhullnode\thecurrentnode)$)}
    \fi
}
}
\hullpath
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[use Hobby shortcut,scale=3,transform shape]
\node (f) {f}
    child { node (g) {g} 
      child { node (a) {a}
    }
      child { node (b) {b}
    }
  }
    child { node (h) {h}
      child { node (c) {c}
      }
  };

\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
\fill[red,opacity=0.3] \hobbyconvexpath{a,g,b}{10pt};
\end{pgfonlayer}

\draw[blue,dashed]($(hobbyhullnode1)!10pt!-90:(hobbyhullnode0)$)--
($(hobbyhullnode1)!10pt!-90:(hobbyhullnode0)$)..($(hobbyhullnode1)!10pt!180:(hobbyhullnode0)$)..
($(hobbyhullnode2)!0.5!(hobbyhullnode1)$) ..
($(hobbyhullnode2)!10pt!-90:(hobbyhullnode1)$)..($(hobbyhullnode2)!10pt!180:(hobbyhullnode1)$)..($(hobbyhullnode3)!0.5!(hobbyhullnode2)$)..
($(hobbyhullnode3)!10pt!-90:(hobbyhullnode2)$)..($(hobbyhullnode3)!10pt!180:(hobbyhullnode2)$)
..($(hobbyhullnode4)!0.5!(hobbyhullnode3)$) .. cycle;

\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
\fill[green!50!lime,opacity=0.4] \hobbyconvexpath{g,f,h,c}{10pt};
\end{pgfonlayer}

\draw[blue,dashed]($(hobbyhullnode1)!10pt!-90:(hobbyhullnode0)$)--
($(hobbyhullnode1)!10pt!-90:(hobbyhullnode0)$)..($(hobbyhullnode1)!10pt!180:(hobbyhullnode0)$)..
($(hobbyhullnode2)!0.5!(hobbyhullnode1)$) ..
($(hobbyhullnode2)!10pt!-90:(hobbyhullnode1)$)..($(hobbyhullnode2)!10pt!180:(hobbyhullnode1)$)..($(hobbyhullnode3)!0.5!(hobbyhullnode2)$)..
($(hobbyhullnode3)!10pt!-90:(hobbyhullnode2)$)..($(hobbyhullnode3)!10pt!180:(hobbyhullnode2)$)
..($(hobbyhullnode4)!0.5!(hobbyhullnode3)$) ..
($(hobbyhullnode4)!10pt!-90:(hobbyhullnode3)$)..($(hobbyhullnode4)!10pt!180:(hobbyhullnode3)$)
..($(hobbyhullnode5)!0.5!(hobbyhullnode4)$) .. cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[use Hobby shortcut,scale=3,transform shape]
\node (f) {f}
    child { node (g) {g} 
      child { node (a) {a}
    }
      child { node (b) {b}
    }
  }
    child { node (h) {h}
      child { node (c) {c}
      }
  };

\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
\fill[orange,opacity=0.4] \hobbyconvexpath{a,g,h,b}{13pt};
\end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[use Hobby shortcut,scale=3,transform shape]
\node (f) {f}
    child { node (g) {g} 
      child { node (a) {a}
    }
      child { node (b) {b}
    }
  }
    child { node (h) {h}
      child { node (c) {c}
      }
  };

\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
\fill[cyan,opacity=0.4] \hobbyconvexpath{b,g,f,h}{10pt};
\end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Below is a snippet of the error.

```
...
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty

LaTeX Warning: You have requested, on input line 53, version
               `2012/12/21' of package expl3,
               but only version
               `2011/04/09 v2222 L3 Experimental code bundle wrapper'
               is available.


/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty:65: P
ackage xparse Error: Support package l3kernel too old.

See the xparse package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.65   }

Please install an up to date version of l3kernel
using your TeX package manager or from CTAN.

Loading xparse will abort!

) (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hobby/pml3array.sty
\l_array_base_int=\count183
\l_array_top_int=\count184
\l_array_tmp_int=\count185
\g_array_base_int=\count186
)
....
```

I've removed and installed `3kernel l3packages l3experimental` but that did not help either.

```
sudo tlmgr remove --force l3kernel l3packages l3experimental
sudo tlmgr install l3kernel l3packages l3experimental
```

Looking at `/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty` I notice that it is looking for `expl3`, which is not installed. Please see below.

```
...
\RequirePackage{expl3}[2012/12/21]
\@ifpackagelater{expl3}{2012/12/21}
  {}
  {%
    \PackageError{xparse}{Support package l3kernel too old}
      {%
        Please install an up to date version of l3kernel\MessageBreak
        using your TeX package manager or from CTAN.\MessageBreak
        \MessageBreak
        Loading xparse will abort!%
      }%
    \endinput
  }
...
```

Would you please point me in the right direction, as to how may I solve the problem?

Comment: Could you provide a MWE which shows your error?  I updated just yesterday to the most recent update.  Everything is working fine for me.  So sample code might help us narrow down what's going on.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).

Comment: Thanks Peter. I appreciate you all taking the time to look at the problem.

Comment: You can't boil that down to something easier to sift through?

Comment: Ellett, I've made edits to the question. I hope now it would more sense. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: I don't seem to have any problems compiling your document as posted.

Comment: Thanks Ellett for looking into the problem. Perhaps I messed up my local installation during the update. I'll try reinstalling MacTex.

Comment: Could we see the log just before the `LaTeX Warning`? Clearly you are managing to load `expl3` from _somewhere_: my guess is a 'local' installation, but without the relevant part of the log it's impossible to say.

Comment: Thanks Joseph. As with Ellett, I can now compile the code as is. I think,  the remnants of 2011 version were causing the problem. To solve it, I removed `/usr/local/texlive`, `/Applications/TeX` and `/Library/TeX`. Later I installed MacTex and then updated everything `sudo tlmgr update --all`. Whatever the problem was, it was resolved by starting from scratch. I didn't have time to continue troubleshooting and a fresh setup was much faster.