# How to draw an envelope around a subset of graph nodes in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, graphs

I have an arbitrary graph and want to draw an envelope around/behind a certain subset of the graphs nodes. To clarify what I want to achieve, I have made a sketch in Inkscape:

[image: Envelope example]

Any ideas how to realize something like that?

Comment: See: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/211282/boundary-around-nodes-corresponding-to-euler-walk,  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/297222/tikz-how-to-create-rectangle-around-two-nodes-which-are-located-diagonally-to, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70999/highlight-a-group-of-nodes-in-a-tikz-tree.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the suggestions of posts related to my question brought me on the right track: [Highlight a group of nodes in a tikz tree](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70999/highlight-a-group-of-nodes-in-a-tikz-tree?noredirect=1&lq=1)

One has to exchange expressions of the form \atan2(x, y) with \atan2(y, x) to get it working correctly.