# Draw a shape around a set of nodes using TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

I want to draw a smooth shape around a set of nodes, as illustrated here (I produced this picture manually):
[image]

Is there a way to do that automatically with TikZ or one of its extensions? By *automatically*, I mean something like: specifiying the positions of the nodes to be included in the shape, as well as the margin between the nodes and the shape.

Comment: Does [padded boundary of convex hull](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27171/13304) and [Hobby path realization in convex hull approach](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/71638/13304) help?

Comment: Can we see the code you've got? If you post the code for the nodes, it would be easy to add the shapes around them.

Comment: This sounds like an application for the `fitting` library

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino: the http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27171/13304 makes it perfectly. Thanks a lot! (maybe should I mark my post as duplicate, now?)

Comment: @cfr: the figure was drawn manually. I added this point in the question.