# I would like to draw sets of points with subsets connected via colored areas, then connecting sets of such images by arrows

Tags: tikz-pgf, technical-drawing

It is probably more of a tikz question by I will ask it nevertheless: 
how do you make something like this picture in latex?

[image]

I need to control which ones are linked together and then draw pictures of collections of such sets of points each picture connected to the others by arrows...

Comment: Welcome! I think this problem is called _convex hull_. You can see how to do it for instance **[here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71638/hobby-path-realization-in-convex-hull-approach)**. You could also try drawing on a background layer with the `rounded corner` option. For connecting these with arrows, you can draw an invisible node around each picture with the _fit_ library.

Comment: Does this picture come from https://mathlesstraveled.com/tag/haskell?

Answer (score 2):

This is the solution following the comment of Tom Bombadil:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10]{standalone}

\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main}

% taken from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/356877/42803
\def\drawpolygon#1,#2,#3;{
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
        \begin{scope}[transparency group,opacity=0.5]
            \filldraw[#1,line width=15,join=round] (#2.center) foreach \A in {#3}{--(\A.center)}--cycle;
        \end{scope}
    \end{pgfonlayer}
}

\tikzset{point/.style={circle,fill, minimum size=9pt,
              inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt}}

\newcommand{\drawpoints}[2]{
    \begin{scope}[shift={(#1)}]
        \foreach \a in {1,...,#2} 
            \coordinate (\a) at (90+\a*360/#2:1) {};
        \foreach \a in {1,...,#2} 
            \node[point] at (\a) {};
    \end{scope}
}

\newcommand{\drawsubset}[4]{
    \begin{scope}[shift={(#1)}]
        \foreach \a in {1,...,#2} 
            \coordinate (\a) at (90+\a*360/#2:1) {};
        \drawpolygon #4,#3;
    \end{scope}
}

\newcommand{\drawsubseta}[4]{
    \drawsubset{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}
    \drawpoints{#1}{#2}
}

\newcommand{\drawsubsetb}[6]{
    \drawsubset{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}
    \drawsubset{#1}{#2}{#5}{#6}
    \drawpoints{#1}{#2}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\drawsubseta{0,0}{5}{1,2,3,4,5}{red}
\drawsubseta{4,0}{5}{1,3,5}{green}
\drawsubsetb{8,0}{5}{1,2,4}{green}{3,5}{magenta}
\drawsubsetb{12,0}{5}{1,3}{brown}{2,5}{orange}
\drawsubseta{16,0}{5}{1,2,4,5}{red}
\drawpoints{0,4}{5}
\drawsubsetb{4,4}{5}{3,4,5}{green}{1,2}{magenta}
\drawsubseta{8,4}{5}{1,2,3,4}{red}
\drawsubseta{12,4}{5}{1,2,5}{green}
\drawsubsetb{16,4}{5}{1,2}{brown}{3,5}{orange}
\drawsubseta{0,-4}{7}{1,2,5}{orange}
\drawsubsetb{4,-4}{6}{3,4,5}{green}{1,2,6}{magenta}
\drawsubsetb{8,-4}{7}{1,3,4,5}{red}{2,6}{green}
\drawsubseta{12,-4}{4}{1,2,3,4}{green}
\drawsubsetb{16,-4}{7}{1,2,5}{brown}{3,4,6,7}{orange}

\node[outer sep = 1.2cm,circle] (a) at (4,-4) {};
\node[outer sep = 1.2cm,circle] (b) at (16,4) {};
\draw[line width=2pt,->] (a) to[out=20,in=-160] (b);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A `\tikzRegConHull` that creates a set of `dots` nodes which gets connected according to a list of list.
Each entry in the `,` list is a hull where the corners are separated by `;`.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\newcommand*\tikzrchset{\pgfqkeys{/tikz/regular convex hull}}
\tikzrchset{
  /tikz/rch/.code=\tikzrchset{#1},
  dots/.initial=5, dot diameter/.initial=10pt, padding/.initial=5pt,
  radius/.initial=1cm, hull opacity/.initial=.5, phase/.initial=0,
  dot/.style={shape=circle, fill=black, inner sep=+0pt,
              minimum size=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/regular convex hull/dot diameter}},
  hull colors/.style={/utils/exec=\def\pgfmathcounter{0},
    /utils/rch/.code={\edef\pgfmathcounter{\pgfinteval{\pgfmathcounter+1}}%
                      \tikzrchset{hull \pgfmathcounter/.append style={##1}}},
    /utils/rch/.list={#1}},
  hull/.style={draw, fill, line join=round, line cap=round,
    line width=(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/regular convex hull/dot diameter})
              +(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/regular convex hull/padding})}}
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\tikzrchElemSplit}{>{\SplitList{;}}m}{\tikzrchElemStart#1\relax}
\def\tikzrchElemStart#1#2\relax {\tikzset{insert path=(#1.center)}%
  \ProcessList{#2}{\tikzrchElems}\tikzset{insert path=--cycle}}
\newcommand*\tikzrchElems[1]{\tikzset{insert path=--(#1.center)}}
\newcommand*{\tikzRegConHull}[2][]{
  \path\pgfextra{\tikzrchset{#1}}
    foreach \rchDOTi in {1,...,\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/regular convex hull/dots}}{
      node[regular convex hull/dot,regular convex hull/dot \rchDOTi/.try]
      (rch \rchDOTi) at ({\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/regular convex hull/phase}
                    +360/(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/regular convex hull/dots})*\rchDOTi}:
                          \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/regular convex hull/radius}){}}
    foreach[/tikz/behind path, /tikz/name prefix=rch\space, count=\rchELEMi,
      /tikz/execute at begin to={\scope[transparency group,
          opacity=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/regular convex hull/hull opacity}]},
      /tikz/execute at end to=\endscope] \rchELEM in {#2} {
      (0,0) edge[regular convex hull/hull, regular convex hull/hull \rchELEMi/.try,
        name prefix=rch\space, to path=%
          \pgfextra{\expandafter\tikzrchElemSplit\expandafter{\rchELEM}}](0,0)};}
\begin{document}
\newcommand*\makefives[1]{\tikzRegConHull{#1}\pgfmatrixnextcell\tikzRegConHull{#1}
        \pgfmatrixnextcell\tikzRegConHull{#1}\pgfmatrixnextcell\tikzRegConHull{#1}
        \pgfmatrixnextcell\tikzRegConHull{#1}\pgfmatrixendrow}
\tikz\matrix[
  row sep=7mm, column sep=7mm,
  every cell/.append code=\tikzrchset{phase=18-72*(\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn-1)},
  hull colors/.style args={#1 -> #2}{
    /utils/temp/.style={/tikz/row ##1/.append code=\tikzrchset{hull colors={#2}}},
    /utils/temp/.list={#1}},
  hull colors/.list={{2, 3}    -> purple,                   {4, 5} -> green,
                     {6, 7, 8} -> {orange, brown!75!black}, 9  -> black,
                     {10, 11}  -> {purple, green},          12 -> red!70!black}]{
 & & \tikzRegConHull{} \\
 \makefives{1;5}        \makefives{2;4}
 \makefives{1;2;4}      \makefives{3;4;5}
 \makefives{1;5, 2;3}   \makefives{2;5, 1;3}   \makefives{3;5, 1;2}
 \makefives{1;2;3;4}
 \makefives{1;2, 3;4;5} \makefives{3;5, 1;2;4}
 & & \tikzRegConHull{1;2;3;4;5} \\};
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

[upside](https://i.stack.imgur.com/23abq.png)