# Rounded polygons

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to realize beautiful rounded polygons enclosing some nodes.

If we use `\draw[rounded corners]` the resulting polygon does not include our vertices.

```
\documentclass[border=5]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

%Coordinates of the vertices
\foreach \i/\r in {0/1,1/0.8,2/1.2,3/1,4/0.9,5/1.1}
    \coordinate (c\i) at (60*\i:\r) {};

%The vertices
\foreach \i in {0,...,5} \node[fill=black,circle,inner sep=1pt] at (c\i) {};

%The Polygon
\draw[rounded corners=5] (c0)--(c1)--(c2)--(c3)--(c4)--(c5)--cycle;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Some nodes and a rounded polygon that fails to entail them]

We can shift the center points of the polygon like this,
but for each node the direction of shifting changes
and had to be calculated.

[image: A larger polygon containing now the nodes]

I know of the two approaches in [this very much related Question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/356564/macro-for-rounded-polygon-around-some-nodes) but both answers have their drawbacks. Symbol 1s answer actually uses `filldraw` so we can not have multiple polygons intersect. My answer is just ridiculously slow for compiling.

So my answer is: **What is a nice way of drawing a polygon around some nodes?**

Comment: I accepted the answer but sadly for polygons with both flat and wide angels the 'rounded corners' approach is quite ugly. I will never find my desired solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not think it is necessary to reinvent this since this has already a very nice answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/133670/121799).

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\makeatletter
\usetikzlibrary{decorations,backgrounds}
\def\pgfdecoratedcontourdistance{0pt}
\pgfset{
  decoration/contour distance/.code=%
    \pgfmathsetlengthmacro\pgfdecoratedcontourdistance{#1}}
\pgfdeclaredecoration{contour lineto closed}{start}{%
  \state{start}[
    next state=draw,
    width=0pt,
    persistent precomputation=\let\pgf@decorate@firstsegmentangle\pgfdecoratedangle]{%
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointlineattime{.5}
      {\pgfqpoint{0pt}{\pgfdecoratedcontourdistance}}
      {\pgfqpoint{\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentlength}{\pgfdecoratedcontourdistance}}}%
  }%
  \state{draw}[next state=draw, width=\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentlength]{%
    \ifpgf@decorate@is@closepath@%
      \pgfmathsetmacro\pgfdecoratedangletonextinputsegment{%
        -\pgfdecoratedangle+\pgf@decorate@firstsegmentangle}%
    \fi
    \pgfmathsetlengthmacro\pgf@decoration@contour@shorten{%
      -\pgfdecoratedcontourdistance*cot(-\pgfdecoratedangletonextinputsegment/2+90)}%
    \pgfpathlineto
      {\pgfpoint{\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentlength+\pgf@decoration@contour@shorten}
      {\pgfdecoratedcontourdistance}}%
    \ifpgf@decorate@is@closepath@%
      \pgfpathclose
    \fi
  }%
  \state{final}{}%
}
\makeatother
\tikzset{
  contour/.style={
    decoration={
      name=contour lineto closed,
      contour distance=#1
    },
    decorate}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \i/\r in {0/1,1/0.8,2/1.2,3/1,4/0.9,5/1.1}
    \coordinate (c\i) at (60*\i:\r);
\foreach \i in {0,...,5} \node[fill=black,circle,inner sep=1pt] at (c\i) {};

\draw[preaction={contour=-5pt,rounded corners=5,draw}] (c0)--(c1)--(c2)--(c3)--(c4)--(c5)--cycle;   
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\draw[draw=none,preaction={contour=-5pt,rounded corners=5,draw}] (c0)--(c1)--(c2)--(c3)--(c4)--(c5)--cycle;
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can calculate the barycenter of all vertices (in the code is the node `(b)`), and then scale the polygon relatively to its barycenter (in the code using `scale around={1.3:(b)}` stored in a style `s`).

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=7pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    %Coordinates of the vertices
    \coordinate(b); % <-- will contain the barycenter of the vertices
    \foreach[count=\n from 0] \i/\r in {0/1,1/0.8,2/1.2,3/1,4/0.9,5/1.1}
        \path (60*\i:\r) coordinate (c\i) ($(c\i)!\n/(\n+1)!(b)$) coordinate(b);

    %The vertices
    \foreach \i in {0,...,5} \node[fill=black,circle,inner sep=1pt] at (c\i) {};

    %The rounded polygon
    \draw[rounded corners=5,s/.style={scale around={1.3:(b)}}]
      ([s]c0) foreach \i in{1,...,5}{--([s]c\i)}--cycle;

  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that this works in general, i.e. also for an L-shaped polygon, say? Or is your answer tailor-made for the polygon of the above question?

Comment: @marmot it "works" only for convex polygons with not very strange distribution of the vertices.