# How to color some areas of a branching diagram

Tags: diagrams, tikz-trees, trees

do you have an idea how could I reproduce the brancing-diagram in this picture? I suppose that it was made with `tikz` or `pst-tree` but I don't know how, especially how to get those coloured areas.

[image: Branching diagram I want to reproduce]

The tree in the picture is taken from this [presentation](http://kiluvonprince.de/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/MappingIrreality.pdf)

MWE (produces almost the same tree but not the coloured areas):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows,decorations.pathmorphing,trees}


\begin{document}

\vspace{5cm}
\tikzstyle{level 1}=[level distance=3cm, sibling distance=3cm,very thick]
\tikzstyle{level 2}=[level distance=3cm, sibling distance=2cm]
\tikzstyle{level 3}=[level distance=3cm, sibling distance=1.5cm]

\tikzstyle{empty node} = [circle,draw,minimum width=1pt,fill=white,inner sep=2pt]
\tikzstyle{end} = [circle,draw,inner sep=1.2,fill=black, minimum width=2pt]

\begin{tikzpicture}[grow=right, sloped]
\node[end] {}
child[loosely dotted] {
    node[end] {}        
    child{
        node[end]{}
        child{
            node[end] {}
        }
        child{
            node[end] {}
        }
    }
    child {
        node[end] {}
            child{
            node[end] {}
            }
            child{
            node[end] {}
            }
        }
}
child[loosely dotted]{
    node[end]{}
    child{
        node[end] {}
    }
    child{
        node[end] {}
    }
}
child {
    node[empty node,label=above:{\Large{\textit{i}$_c$}}] {}
    child[loosely dashed] {
        node[end] {}
        child{
            node[end]{}
            child{
                node[end]{}    
            }
            child{
                node[end]{}    
            }
        }
    }
    child[dashed]{
        node[end] {}
        child{
        node[end]{}
        child{
        node[end]{}    
    }
        child{
        node[end]{}    
    }
    }
    }
}
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Thank you very much in advance!!!

Comment: What did you try sofar. Please add a MWE (starting with \documentclass and ending with \end{document})

Comment: Drawing the tree is easy. I would recommend using `forest`. Drawing the coloured regions can be done with the TikZ `fit` library. Getting the exact shapes might involve some work.  Perhaps you should try that and post your code here when you get stuck.

Comment: @AlanMunn Thanks! I'll try the fit library. I've added a MWE example which produces the tree using tikz, but perhaps it is even easier with forest.

Comment: You can have a look to [Hobby path realization in convex hull approach](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/71638/13304) for an automatic solution.

Comment: There's at least one very similar question to this somewhere. Specific to Forest, possibly. Certainly with Forest solutions.

Answer (score 5):

Your code doesn't produce a tree with the structure shown, at least when I compile it, and it isn't clear how to apply the shading to your tree. So, I adapted it to produce the illustrated structure, after translating it to Forest. The `backgrounds` library is used for the shadings. Most of the packages and libraries you list in your code are egregious.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,11pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{% \tikzstyle is deprecated
  empty node/.style = {circle,draw,minimum width=1pt,fill=white,inner sep=2pt},
  end/.style = {circle,draw,inner sep=1.2,fill=black, minimum width=2pt,},
}%
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    grow=0,
    edge+={loosely dotted, very thick},
    end,
    s sep'=5mm,
    fit=band,
  },
  where level<=1{calign=fixed edge angles}{},
  before drawing tree={
    tempdima/.max={x}{tree},
    where n children=0{x/.register=tempdima}{},
  }
  [
    [
      [[[][]][[][]]]
      [[[][]][[][]]]
    ]
    [
      [
        [[][]][[][]]
      ]
      [
        [[][]][[][]]
      ]
      [, for current and ancestors={edge+={solid}}, empty node, very thick, label=above:{\Large{\textit{i}$_c$}}
        [, for tree={edge+={loosely dashed}} [[][]]]
        [, for tree={edge+={dashed}} [[][]]]
      ]
    ]
  ]
  \begin{scope}[on background layer]
    \begin{scope}[transparency group, opacity=.25]
      \draw [blue, line width=30pt, line cap=round] (!r) -- (!rll);
      \node [fit=(!rlll) (!rll1) (!rlllll) (!rll111), fill=green, rounded corners] {};
      \path [fill, draw, magenta, line width=20pt, rounded corners] (!r1.center) -- (!r111.center) -- (!rF.center) -- (!rl2L.center) -- (!rl2l.center) -- (!rl2.center) -- cycle;
    \end{scope}
  \end{scope}
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: shaded tree]

Comment: +1 Very nice way to do the colouring. You're missing a `solid` edge on the top branch from the root.

Comment: Thanks. @AlanMunn Left as an exercise for the reader?

Comment: @AlanMunn Better now?

Comment: Perfect........ :)

Comment: @AlanMunn I got rid of `a`, too. Seemed excessive.