# Autogenerate aliases based on scope

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to be able to refer to nodes inside a scope from outside the scope by specifying their scope and name as in [TiKZ node name prefixes in scopes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128049/tikz-node-name-prefixes-in-scopes) The solution proposed there renames the nodes so that it's not possible to refer to the nodes inside of the scope without knowing in which scope they're in.

The code below is what I'm trying to achieve, but I'm unable to figure out how to add an alias inside the name/.code argument. My attempt of pasting the alias/.code text from the tikz source didn't work and broke the naming as well.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/128049/86}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\tikzstyle{vertex}=[circle,draw,fill=black!20]

\makeatletter
\tikzset{%
  prefix node name/.code={%
    \tikzset{%
      name/.code={{\edef\tikz@fig@name{##1}}} %don't know how to create alias from ##1 (node name) to #1 ##1 (scope name node name)
    }%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{tikzpicture}

% ---- Copy 1
\begin{scope}[yshift=-32pt,prefix node name=G1]
  \node[vertex] (u) at (0, 0) {u};
  \node[vertex] (v) at (1, 0) {v};
  \draw (u) -- (v);
\end{scope}

% ---- Copy 2
\begin{scope}[yshift=32pt,prefix node name=G2]
  \node[vertex] (u) at (0, 0) {u};
  \node[vertex] (v) at (1, 0) {v};
  \draw (u) -- (v);
\end{scope}

\draw (G1 u) -- (G2 v);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you consider using `pics` instead of `scopes`? Every `pic` can have its name asprefix for inner nodes. An example: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/170686/1952

Comment: I've added an example with `pics` to the linked question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/207513/1952

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the comments to the OPs question indicate, in the latest PGF release node names can be prefixed within a `pic`. However, this mechanism can also be used in scopes. Note that in order to get the space the OP requires the prefix must end with `\space`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[vertex/.style={circle, draw, fill=black!20}]

% ---- Copy 1
\begin{scope}[yshift=-32pt, name prefix=G1\space]
  \node[vertex] (u) at (0, 0) {u};
  \node[vertex] (v) at (1, 0) {v};
  \draw (u) -- (v);
\end{scope}

% ---- Copy 2
\begin{scope}[yshift=32pt, name prefix=G2\space] 
  \node[vertex] (u) at (0, 0) {u};
  \node[vertex] (v) at (1, 0) {v};
  \draw (u) -- (v);
\end{scope}

\draw (G1 u) -- (G2 v);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

For completeness, this looks like what you wanted to have with the `alias` code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{%
  vertex/.style={circle,draw,fill=black!20},
  prefix node name/.code={%
    \tikzset{%
      name/.code={\edef\tikz@fig@name{#1 ##1}%
        \tikz@fig@mustbenamed%
          \expandafter\def\expandafter\tikz@alias\expandafter{%
        \tikz@alias\pgfnodealias{##1}{\tikz@fig@name}%
        }%
      }%
    }%
  }
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% ---- Copy 1
\begin{scope}[yshift=-32pt,prefix node name=G1]
  \node[vertex] (u) at (0, 0) {u};
  \node[vertex] (v) at (1, 0) {v};
  \draw (u) -- (v);
\end{scope}

% ---- Copy 2
\begin{scope}[yshift=32pt,prefix node name=G2]
  \node[vertex] (u) at (0, 0) {u};
  \node[vertex] (v) at (1, 0) {v};
  \draw (u) -- (v);
  \draw (G1 u) to[bend right] (v);
\end{scope}

\draw (G1 u) -- (G2 v);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]