# How reference internal nodes with the same name in tikz sub pictures

Tags: tikz-pgf

Please see my comment for the motivation.

Here is what I am doing:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \node (a) at (0,0)
     {
        \input{Diagrams/model1.tex}
     };
    \node (b) at (a) [anchor=west,xshift=50ex]
     {
        \input{Diagrams/model2.tex}
     };


     % connect nodes from these two separate plots that happen to have the same name
    \draw [<->] (a.outlier)--(b.outlier);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Here is the MWE that simulates this case:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning,arrows}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=10ex]
   \node (a) at (0,0)
     {
     % please see comment, this picture is actually being imported from a separate .tex file but MWE implements differently because I can't load files in a post: 
     \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node (aSub1) {aSub1};
        \node (aSub2) [below of=aSub1] {aSub2};
        \node (outlier1) [below of=aSub2] {outlier};
        \draw [->] (aSub1) -- (aSub2);
     \end{tikzpicture}
     };
    \node (b) at (a) [anchor=west,xshift=50ex]
     {
        % please see comment, this picture is actually being imported from a separate .tex file but MWE implements differently because I can't load files in a post: 
        \begin{tikzpicture}
           \node (bSub1) {bSub1};
            \node (bSub2) [below of=bSub1] {bSub2};
            \node (outlier2) [below of=bSub2] {outlier2};
            \draw [->] (bSub1) -- (bSub2);
         \end{tikzpicture}
     };
   \draw [<->] (a)--(b);
   % now draw a line between sub-nodes of the two nested pictures where the scope of the two "outlier" nodes is local to the sub-picture
   \draw [<->] (outlier1) -- (outlier2); % this doesn't work 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

What I want:

[image]

Comment: Do not use `tikzpicture` inside another `tikzpicture`.

Comment: This MWE shows everything in one file.  In my application, the subpictures are different models stored in individual files for re-use, which are then imported via \input{} commands rather than \begin{tikzpicture} in the MWE above.  Unfortunately, the most interpretable notation involves name conflicts between the models.

Comment: Well, it is hard to help without knowledge of what you want exactly. To draw your sample above, it is easy to use two columns of nodes and simply connect them. As I said, nesting `tikzpicture`s is not good.

Comment: @Sigur thanks please see new MWE code comments and my comment above.  The MWE just simulates the import of multiple files

Comment: @Sigur is right. Even if the nested `tikzpicture` is in a file that you input in a node, it is still a nested `tikzpicture`, and thus no good. You can get what you want with `pic`s very easily. (And in principle you can make the stuff above work with some `name prefix` or `name suffix`, but it is really bad practice.)

Comment: For future reference.  A related issue is addressed here:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128049/tikz-node-name-prefixes-in-scopes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to achieve can be done with `local bounding box`es. BTW, you are loading `positioning` but not use it. I fixed that, too.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=8ex]
    \begin{scope}[local bounding box=a]
        \node (aSub1) {aSub1};
        \node (aSub2) [below=of aSub1] {aSub2};
        \node (outlier1) [below=of aSub2] {outlier};
        \draw [->] (aSub1) -- (aSub2);
    \end{scope} 
    \begin{scope}[local bounding box=b,xshift=50ex]
        \node (bSub1) {bSub1};
        \node (bSub2) [below=of bSub1] {bSub2};
        \node (outlier2) [below=of bSub2] {outlier2};
        \draw [->] (bSub1) -- (bSub2);
   \end{scope}
   \draw [<->] (a)--(b);
   \draw [<->] (outlier1) -- (outlier2); 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can make things simpler by also using a `name prefix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=8ex]
    \begin{scope}[local bounding box=a,name prefix=a-]
        \node (Sub1) {aSub1};
        \node (Sub2) [below=of Sub1] {aSub2};
        \node (outlier) [below=of Sub2] {outlier};
        \draw [->] (Sub1) -- (Sub2);
    \end{scope} 
    \begin{scope}[local bounding box=b,xshift=50ex,name prefix=b-]
        \node (Sub1) {bSub1};
        \node (Sub2) [below=of Sub1] {bSub2};
        \node (outlier) [below=of Sub2] {outlier2};
        \draw [->] (Sub1) -- (Sub2);
   \end{scope}
   \draw [<->] (a)--(b);
   \draw [<->] (a-outlier) -- (b-outlier); 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please, correct if I'm wrong: the 1st solution works since `\draw [<->] (a)--(b);` connects the center of the bounding boxes, which have the same height with `xSub2` in the midle, right?

Comment: The name prefix feature is exactly what I needed, since the primary motivation is not to have to rename nodes in different files where conflicts might exist.  Thanks

Comment: @Sigur It connects the bounding boxes in the same way as it would connect rectangular nodes by computing `\pgfpointshapeborder{<shape>}{<point>}` and connecting these points. So it does not connect the centers of the scopes, but the connecting lines do attach to the vertical centers (in this case, because it is a horizontal connection) of the edge facing the other scope, which is probably what you meant by center.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat, thanks. I was thinking why the connection is horizontal exactly in the middle? In other words, if box on the left has 4 lines instead of 3, the connection would be horizontal but not from the *text node* visually. I'm thinking on balanced boxes.  But I think I got the idea.

Comment: @Sigur Yes, if the number of nodes was not balances (and the OP introduces no vertical shift), the connection is not vertical. The `local bounding box` node here is the same as the one you would obtain by using a rectangular `fit` node of all nodes in that scope (of `inner sep` 0pt). The `local bounding box` also takes into account draw commands in the scope, which `fit` does not, but in this case there would be no difference.

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this, using two pictures and connecting nodes between them.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning,arrows}
\tikzset{node distance=2cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \node (aSub1) {aSub1};
  \node (aSub2) [below of=aSub1] {aSub2};
  \node (outlier1) [below of=aSub2] {outlier};
  \draw [->] (aSub1) -- (aSub2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\hspace{5cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \node (bSub1) {bSub1};
  \node (bSub2) [below of=bSub1] {bSub2};
  \node (outlier2) [below of=bSub2] {outlier2};
  \draw [->] (bSub1) -- (bSub2);
  \draw [<->] (aSub2) -- (bSub2);
  \draw [<->] (outlier1) -- (outlier2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks for this suggestion.  Sorry if the OP was unclear that I needed to avoid resolving name conflicts by renaming the nodes in the individual files.  Seems like "name prefix" is the best approach

Comment: @mkk, good. I hope you have success.