# How to use variables in node keys in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-node

I have used variable `\x` while drawing nodes using TiKZ. The drawing part works well without any problems. I have also added keys to the nodes so that they can be linked later. I am facing a curious problem. The node key works if the `\x` is a whole number, but doesn't work if it is a decimal.

For example, in the code below, I am using the key as `\x g2y`.

```
\fill[fill=yellow]
\foreach \x in {2.5,7,11.5} 
{ (\x,10) circle(.45) node(\x g2y) {}};
```

Now when I try to use the keys from here, only the key with `\x` value 7 works. For other values of `\x` like 2.5 and 11.5 it gives an error:

```
ERROR: Package pgf Error: No shape named 2 is known.
```

Somehow, the entire decimal value of the number is not being passed to the key, only the whole number before the decimal. How can this be resolved?

[image]

MWE is appended below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.5]

\fill (9,13.5)[fill=yellow] circle(.5) node (g1){};

 \fill[fill=yellow]
 \foreach \x in {2.5,7,11.5} 
 { (\x,10) circle(.45) node(\x g2y) {}};
% works here with only 7
\draw [red!50,thick]\foreach \x in {7}
 {(g1)--(\x g2y)};

% doesn't works here with 2.5 and 11.5
% \draw [red!50,thick]\foreach \x in {2.5,7,11.5} 
% {(g1)--(\x g2y)};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: See also e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/28242/586

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that TikZ uses `.` to access an anchor of a node, for example `a.west`. So when you have a node called `2.5g2y`, and use that in a `\draw`, TikZ thinks that is a node called `2`, and the anchor would be `5g2y`.

I don't know if it's possible to use periods in node names, but a workaround is to add a `count` to your loop, and use that value instead.

Unrelated comment: in general the `minimal` class should be avoided, see [Why should the minimal class be avoided?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42114/why-should-the-minimal-class-be-avoided)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.5]

\fill (9,13.5)[fill=yellow] circle(.5) node (g1){};

 \fill[fill=yellow]
 \foreach [count=\i] \x in {2.5,7,11.5} 
 { (\x,10) circle(.45) node(\i g2y) {}};

\draw [red!50,thick]\foreach \x in {1,2,3}
 {(g1)--(\x g2y)};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the workaround. Have updated the MWE with article class.